# Lightning Lead Convert Modal

Tags: lightning-experience, lead-conversion, convert

Prior to the ***Summer 19 Release*** the '**Convert**' button on Leads would open in the a **modal popup** as shown below:

[image]

However now when our users click the convert button the screen opens in a **sub tab** and does not display as nicely:

[image]

I cannot find any reference of this change in the release notes or anywhere that this can be changed back to a modal. Any help finding out how to change this would be appreciated or pointed in the direction of any release notes/known issues.

Comment: UPDATE: Spoken to Salesforce support. They investigated the change and have stated this is an "Undocumented Change" in the latest release and there is no way to customise this behaviour at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this convert lead functionality from console application?
If yes, Can you please try to change the application to Sales or something other Console and try.

Comment: We only use console apps for our users in lightning. Previously in a console app this was displayed, unfortunately i cannot go back to demonstrate since all orgs are now on the Summer 19 Release. I have reactivated a standard non-console app and this still displays as a modal there but no longer does in the console apps.